# Update an item in Dynamodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am a newbie to this technology . So bear with my below explanation.

**My usecase :**

I am updating an item in Dynamodb based on primary key(ID) . Basically my record has 4 columns ( ID, description, name , price ) .

The problem here is suppose when i have an item with key 123

```
ID description name price

123 Model      nokia  10
```

when i use above lamda function to update all the columns it is working fine.
But when i try to update only the `description` column it is throwing error that 'ExpressionAttributeValues can't be empty` . So for that i had did some thing like this

```
ExpressionAttributeValues:{
     ":d":event.description ? event.description : null ,
     ":n":event.name ? event.name : null,
     ":p":event.price ? event.price : null
     }
```

But the problem with this is it will update the only value that i had given .
Like if i had given only `description` to `modal1` then it will change that and give the result like this

```
ID description name price

123 Model1  null  null
```

Which is right because that above snippet says to do that.

**What i want to achieve ?**

How can i change that behaviour to acheive like this

```
ID description name price

123 Model1     nokia  10
```

1. Is there a way that it will
       update only the passed parameters and keep the others to its previous
       values ?

Any help is appreciated

**Updatedcode**

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({
    region: "regionname",
    endpoint: "endpointurl"
});
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

var tablename = "Example"; 


var UpdateExpression = "'set";
var ExpressionAttributeValues= {};
var ExpressionAttributeNames= {};
var ID = "xx";
var description = "Iphone";
var name = "xx";
var price = 50;
 var params = { 
    TableName: tablename, 
    Key:{ 
    "ID": ID 
    }
    };
docClient.update(params,onUpdate);
 function onUpdate(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to scan the table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Update succeeded.");
    }
    if(description) { 
        UpdateExpression = UpdateExpression + " description = :d,",
        ExpressionAttributeValues [":d"] =  description ,
        console.log("first...")

        }
        if(name){ 
        UpdateExpression = UpdateExpression + " #na = :n,",
        ExpressionAttributeNames['#na'] = 'name' ,
        ExpressionAttributeValues[":n"] = name ,
        console.log("second...")
        }
        if(price){ 
        UpdateExpression = UpdateExpression + " price = :p',",
        ExpressionAttributeValues[":p"] = price ,
        console.log("third...")
        }        
        console.log(UpdateExpression)
        console.log(ExpressionAttributeNames)
        console.log(ExpressionAttributeValues)
        return (UpdateExpression,ExpressionAttributeNames,ExpressionAttributeValues)
    }
```

When i ran the code i got output like this :

D:\Dynamo>node FullUpdate.js

```
Update succeeded.
first...
second...
third...
'set description = :d, #na = :n, price = :p',
{ '#na': 'name' }
{ ':d': 'Iphone', ':n': 'xx', ':p': 50 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to fabric your query depending on the variables you have, so you have to do something like this

```
UpdateExpression = "set";
ExpressionAttributeValues: {};
ExpressionAttributeNames: {};

if(event.description){
 UpdateExpression = UpdateExpression + "description = :d";
 ExpressionAttributeValues[":d"] = event.description
}
if(event.name){
 UpdateExpression = UpdateExpression + "#na = :n";
 ExpressionAttributeNames['#na'] = 'name'
 ExpressionAttributeValues[":d"] = event.name
}
if(event.price){
 UpdateExpression = UpdateExpression + "price = :p";
 ExpressionAttributeValues[":d"] = event.pice
}
```

be carful of the comma, and log your query to be sure it fits your expectations. 
you can check a function i use for this purpose,

```
update(_id, store_id, opts?) {

    var Key = {
      _id: _id,
      store_id: store_id
    };

    if (Object.keys(opts).length > 0) {
      let UpdateExpression =
        "SET #date = :date, #author = :author";

      let ExpressionAttributeNames = {
        "#date": "date",
        "#author": "author"
      }

      let ExpressionAttributeValues = {
        ":date": new Date().getTime(),
        ":author": localStorage.getItem('user_id')
      }

      if ((opts && opts.title)) {
        UpdateExpression = UpdateExpression + "#title = :title,";
        ExpressionAttributeNames["#title"] = "title";
        ExpressionAttributeValues[":title"] = opts.title
      }

      if ((opts && opts.category)) {
        UpdateExpression = UpdateExpression + "#category = :category,";
        ExpressionAttributeNames["#category"] = "category";
        ExpressionAttributeValues[":category"] = opts.category
      }

      if ((opts && opts.category)) {
        UpdateExpression = UpdateExpression + "#dimension = :dimension,";
        ExpressionAttributeNames["#dimension"] = "dimension";
        ExpressionAttributeValues[":dimension"] = opts.dimension
      }

      if ((opts && opts.category)) {
        UpdateExpression = UpdateExpression + "#destination = :destination,";
        ExpressionAttributeNames["#destination"] = "destination";
        ExpressionAttributeValues[":destination"] = opts.destination
      }

      if ((opts && opts.category)) {
        UpdateExpression = UpdateExpression + "#timeStart = :timeStart,";
        ExpressionAttributeNames["#timeStart"] = "timeStart";
        ExpressionAttributeValues[":timeStart"] = opts.timeStart
      }

      if ((opts && opts.category)) {
        UpdateExpression = UpdateExpression + "#timeEnd = :timeEnd,";
        ExpressionAttributeNames["#timeEnd"] = "timeEnd";
        ExpressionAttributeValues[":timeEnd"] = opts.timeEnd
      }

      if ((opts && opts.publish)) {
        UpdateExpression = UpdateExpression + "#publish = :publish,"
        ExpressionAttributeNames["#publish"] = "publish"
        ExpressionAttributeValues[":publish"] = "x";
      }


      UpdateExpression = UpdateExpression.replace(new RegExp(',$'), '');

      if ((opts && opts.nbviews)) {
        UpdateExpression = UpdateExpression + "ADD #nbviews = :nbviews"
        ExpressionAttributeNames["#nbviews"] = "nbviews"
        ExpressionAttributeValues[":nbviews"] = 1;
      }

      if ((opts && !opts.publish)) {
        UpdateExpression = UpdateExpression + " REMOVE #publish"
        ExpressionAttributeNames["#publish"] = "publish"
      }

      return this.dataService.update(TABLENAME, Key, UpdateExpression, null, ExpressionAttributeNames, ExpressionAttributeValues);
```

Comment: Thanks @Temkit. But i cant use this approach in lambda because it is not accepting `.` in `if(event.description)`.

Comment: what do you mean by " it is not accepting . in if(event.description)" , i don't understand ?

Comment: It is showing `parsing error : unexpected token` in lambda console.

Comment: Can show the code you are using, actually I implemented the function above in lambda

Comment: ohh okay. May be i am missing something . The code is in `UPDATE` section of my question.

Comment: you can't use an IF statement in an Object, check you code at   ExpressionAttributeNames: { .... , and close this before the IF!